# Iframe content not loading

Tags: html, iframe

I'm currently trying to get an iframe to display documents when clicked upon. There are currently four links that use to workl and I'm trying to get  two out of the four are working that where broken. The iframe code that I'm using is:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="800" scrolling="Yes" src="file://\\xxx-xxx\xxxxxx xxxxxx\xxx xxxxxxx" width="100%"></iframe>
```

The (x)'s are there as place holders for source location.

Comment: If you have simply replaced the characters in the `src` with "x" for StackOverflow then your URL format is completely invalid

Comment: I did replace the src with x's for StackOverflow. This code is the same code that was used when the site was originaly made. I'm just trying to get the documents to display again after the page was deleted on accident. Also I was not the one to create the page. Also if you could show me the correct code it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and Paste the contents of src into your navigation bar in your browser. What do you get? If that url doesn't work (and I'm guessing it wont), then you need to find the correct url path to these files. You can perhaps do this by simply searching for the files with the search on your machine. This may work, but I'm not sure that other users will be able to navigate to the files because (and any one feel free to correct me if I'm wrong) file:// url paths will only point to files on your machine. You might have upload these files to the server...

Comment: sorry, I just saw your comment about it being for an internal network

Comment: Not a problem. The files are located on our server and I'm trying to get them to display when the link it clicked upon in the intranet for the company. I'm just really confused, because the code that is posted above is working on two active links, but not the two that i had to remake.

Comment: okay, then you will have to locate those files and copy the url and paste it into the src="[paste correct url here]" line of your code. Are you using windows or mac?

Comment: Ok, so i applied the correct url in src="[correct URL]". But it still will not show the files I need it to show. Under the preview option I have available i can see the files, but when i click save and navigate back to it, I get nothing

Comment: I tried the URL again just to make sure it was not something i did. the URL without the file:// will not work, but when the file:// is added it works

Answer (score 0):

Use a more well-formed URI for your `src=` declaration.  It's not going to work with spaces, and `file://` probably won't work in the majority of browsers.

Comment: It is for an internal network and the browser is IE and have not had any problems so far. But there used to be four active links that all worked until an employee accidently deleted two of the pages. So im trying to rebuild those pages and followed the code word for word from the two remaining pages. only thing that was changed was the src